# Axios + Vue executing same POST twice

Tags: vue.js, axios

While executing a POST in Axios, the request is always sent twice. This is not a CORS issue, as I get two pairs of requests (CORS and POST, and then ANOTHER CORS and POST).

I scaffolded a sample application using the hello-world template and it still exhibits the same behaviour:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    Test
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.create({
            baseURL: 'https://api.example.com'
        }).post('/login', {
            token: 'tokenString'
        }).then((a) => {
            console.log(a)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('err login')
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

I only get the console.log of the second request, but the network tab clearly shows the two pairs of requests, and the API also indicates that two POST requests (with exactly the same parameters) have been made...

Comment: Can you share the code that imports axios as well as the code showing the component that uses this?

Comment: What triggers these requests? Something like an `onsubmit` or an `onclick`?

Comment: I edited the question to answer your questions. @TimWickstrom.com it is imported with `import axios from 'axios'`; @ceejayoz while it was on an `onsubmit`, the behaviour remains when used on a mounted hook.

Comment: Who uses this component? It might be that it is used in two places, or it has some `v-if` or a `key` which makes it render more times?

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle or similar that reproduces this error. I am using Axios on many projects and I have NEVER experienced this. The most likely culprit is either the way you are attaching Axios to Vue OR the component is being duplicated within the application and is actually being triggered twice OR the way the component is being loaded in the router (duplicate pathways). Once the simplified use case is setup in a fiddle it will be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a problem with an extension called Privacy Possum, so it has nothing to do with axios in particular.